# Changed magento inventory configuration & now the add to cart button is missing

Tags: magento, shopping-cart, backend

I followed the instructions [here](http://magentolore.quora.com/Set-default-product-quantity-to-one-in-Magento-i-e-not-default-zero) to change the Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart to **1**.

After I saved the configuration & went back to my product page the **add to cart** button had vanished.

This setting has also seemed to mess up my source code..

```
<div class="product-essential">
<form action="http://????,,/product/58/" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form">
    <div class="no-display">
        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="58" />
        <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
    </div>
```

Any idea why this is happening & how I can revert the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I randomly the solution & it seems to be some kind of glitch with Magento.

I set **Manage Stock** to **yes** & then reindexed the product prices & stock status, still the problem persisted so I tried setting **Manage Stock** to **no**  & then reindexed the product prices & stock status again.  This time when I went back to a product page the add to cart button was back!

Answer (score 1):

This answer applies to newer versions of Magento.

- Go to `Catalog--Manage Products`
- Select the product
- Click `Edit`
- Go to the "Inventory"
- Change Stock Availability to "In Stock" But don't stop! you may notice a red asterisk at `Qty`.
- Enter how many stock items you have.
- Click `Save`

If you don't enter a quantity nothing will change. Your 'buy' button will not appear as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Simply changing a random product quantity forth and back solved it for me for all products.